# Non-standard library placement new with user-defined allocators

Tags: c++

A non-standard library placement new calls a user defined operator new:

```
class T {};

void* operator new(std::size_t s, T*) {
    return new char[s];
}

int main() {
    T* t;
    new(t) T(); // calls operator new above
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I am not wrong, the standard placement new does not call the default operator new. This separation allows the standard allocator to use operator new in `allocate()` to get the memory and placement new to initialize it, with either std::initialize_fill() or `construct()`

Now I don't understand how can I keep the allocation separated from the initialization in a custom allocator when a non-standard placement new is used, since the non-standard placement new always calls a user-defined operator new. Should always force the use of the standard placement new with a static_cast in any allocator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are confusing `operator new()` and the *new operator* to some extend: they have different purposes although they are closely related (Scott Meyers has an item on this in Effective C++ if recall correctly; or, at least, he had an item in an earlier revision as I can't see it right now):

- The purpose of `operator new()` is to make memory available. Typically this amounts to allocating memory from somewhere but in the special case of using placement new it actually does nothing beyond returning its argument.
- The purpose of the new operator, i.e. using an expression calling `operator new()` with the operator call notation (rather than the function call notation) consists of two steps:

  1. it calls the matching `operator new()`
  2. it invokes the matching constructor to construct an object in the obtained location

That said, note that a program is **not** allowed to replace placement versions of the operators `new` and `delete`! It is only permissible to replace the 8 operators which are meant for actual memory allocation (i.e. `operator new(size_t)`, `operator delete(void*)`, the corresponding array array version, and the `std::nothrow_t` version of them). For more detail see 17.6.4.6 [replacement.functions]. The placemement version are really meant to pass through their address argument and (for the `operator delete()` to satisfy the existance in case an exception is thrown during the construction of the object).

The allocator's `allocate()` members are meant to actually provide memory, e.g. by calling `malloc(n)`, `operator new(n)` (but **not** by `new char[n]`), `mmap()`ing pages, etc. It isn't meant to actually construct any objects (see 17.6.3.5 [allocator.requirements] in particular table 28). Actually constructing objects is the purpose of the `construct()` member of allocators. In fact, this function is essentially required to call placement new:

```
template <typename... A>
void allocator::construct(void* address, A&&... args) {
    new(address) T(std::forward<A>(args)...);
}
```

(assuming that `allocator` is responsible for allocating objects of type `T`).

In any case, none of the documented allocation functions (`malloc()`, `operator new()`) calls any of the others. They may internally be implemented in terms of a common function (and probably this is the case) but you can call them in your own allocation functions. Of course, if you are replacing the operators with your own version, you won't call the version provided by the standard library.